# Got "Waiting for download", but cannot flash ESP32-PICO-MINI-02

Tags: esp32

When I press `BOOT + RESET` and try to upload the code, I got
`Can not connect. No serial data received.

In the serial monitor, I can see it enters download mode.

```
16:35:09.454 -> rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x3 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
16:35:09.454 -> waiting for download
16:35:25.084 -> ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
```

When I press `RESET`, I got this:

```
16:35:08.011 -> rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
16:35:08.044 -> invalid header: 0xffffffff
16:35:08.077 -> invalid header: 0xffffffff
16:35:08.142 -> invalid header: 0xffffffff
16:35:08.175 -> invalid header: 0xffffffff
16:35:08.207 -> invalid header: 0xffffffff
16:35:08.273 -> invalid header: 0xffffffff
16:35:08.306 -> invalid header: 0xffffffff
```

Some posts mentioned placing `100nF capacitor` between `EN/GND` will solve, but I already did.

Here's the full schematic. (I have 2 ESP32 on custom board with identical setup)
[image: buttons]
[image: mcus]

I carefully read the [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-pico-mini-02_datasheet_en.pdf), but maybe I missed something?

This is my third version of PCB but still cannot make it to work...
I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you release RESET before you release BOOT.

Comment: @StarCat I did. Exact sequence was `PRESS_BOOT -> PRESS_RESET -> RELEASE_RESET -> RELEASE_BOOT`.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with PCB.
Change some cp10x chip module to ESP-Prog and it works.